# Tensorflow: All variables become nan upon first training run

Tags: tensorflow

I initialized all my variables, but upon the first training run, all variables become nan. I've checked that all variables were initialized before starting training.

## EDIT (Solved)

The image array fed into the net was filled with NaN's causing the problem.

Comment: one thing to check is whether there are NaN's in the gradients, or whether the steps are too large (you can get NaN's when your training diverges)

Comment: (ie, look at norm of optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, [variable])[0])

Comment: All the variables turn into NaN's even when learning rate for the optimizer is set to 0.

Comment: What if you use GradientDescentOptimizer instead of Adam?

Comment: I switched to GradientDescentOptimizer instead of Adam, and still got all variables turning into NaN's after the first training iteration.

Comment: I'm wondering if your initial conditions are bad somehow. If your model gives probability 1 to a label that's incorrect, then you'll end up with infinities in your gradient calculation

Comment: It was a problem with the image array that I fed into the net on ipython notebook. All the values in the array got converted to NaN's. Thanks for helping!